# How to get the particaular day of week in a dropdown when the user selects a date from date picker?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

How to get the  particaular day of week from a  dropdown when the user selects a date from date picker??

I want to let the user select a date drom datepicker. And in the next button i have day field where it contains list of days in a week.

I want to show the particular day for selected date from datepicker when the user clicks on day button. Plz help me?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
NSDate *today=calendarPicker.date;

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *components = [gregorian components: (NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit) fromDate: today];

components.year = [textfield.text intValue]; // Here value for year is fetched from a text field control. Similarly other values like month, date, hour or minute can be changed.

[calendarPicker setDate: [calendar dateFromComponents:components] ]; // Update the date picker control.

[calendar release];
```